# Need to build a calendar component with time slot selections for each date that will map from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to build a calendar component for a React/Redux project.

I'm calling an API that will return back to me a list of dates with corresponding times for each date. There are currently only 3 times available for each date: `AM, PM, ANY` and each time will have it's own unique id.

I'm debating on using a pre existing library or hand rolling my own. Has anyone had to build something similar? If so did you go the roll-your-own route or bring in an external library?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io) in the past - never on React/Redux stuff though.

For time related stuff, have a look at [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)